# How can I easily handle multiple ActionListeners in a Java MVC Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I have written a program that decodes files given a list of character frequencies and text to decode (not relevant to the question, just giving some context). The application uses 4 buttons, however the way I've currently done it is that in my view (this application follows the MVC model) I have methods that add action listeners, that are then called in the controller to give each one a nested class which acts as an ActionListener. This works, however my controller consists of essentially copy pasted code, and I have a feeling there's a way to do this a lot more concisely. I've included my code below, any input is appreciated.

View.java:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.io.File;

public class View
{
    //Declare variables

    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    private JTextArea instructions;

    private JLabel frequenciesFileLoadedLabel;
    private JLabel cipherFileLoadedLabel;

    private JButton frequenciesFileLoadButton;
    private JButton cipherFileLoadButton;

    private JButton decipherByRankButton;
    private JButton decipherByNearestFrequencyButton;

    private boolean cipherLoaded;
    private boolean frequenciesLoaded;

    //Constructor
    public View()
    {
        //Set flags for whether files have been loaded to false
        cipherLoaded = false;
        frequenciesLoaded = false;

        //Set up the main frame
        frame = new JFrame("Text Decrypter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        //Set up the main panel (and the only panel being used)
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 10));
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 290));

        //Set up the instructions that will be displayed on the top of the program
        instructions = new JTextArea("Instructions: upload a file with encrypted text you want to \ndecipher and a file with character frequencies. Once \nboth files are uploaded, you will be able to decipher \nthem by pressing the relevant buttons.", 4, 4);
        instructions.setEditable(false);

        //Set up labels for whether files have been loaded
        frequenciesFileLoadedLabel = new JLabel("No file with character frequencies loaded");
        cipherFileLoadedLabel = new JLabel("No file to decipher loaded");

        //Set up buttons for loading files
        frequenciesFileLoadButton = new JButton("Load character frequencies file");
        cipherFileLoadButton = new JButton("Load file to decipher");

        //Set up buttons for decrypting files and set them to disabled initially
        decipherByRankButton = new JButton("Decipher file by rank of character frequencies");
        decipherByRankButton.setEnabled(false);
        decipherByNearestFrequencyButton = new JButton("Decipher file by the nearest character frequency");
        decipherByNearestFrequencyButton.setEnabled(false);

        //Add all elements of the GUI to the main panel
        mainPanel.add(instructions);
        mainPanel.add(frequenciesFileLoadButton);
        mainPanel.add(frequenciesFileLoadedLabel);
        mainPanel.add(cipherFileLoadButton);
        mainPanel.add(cipherFileLoadedLabel);
        mainPanel.add(decipherByRankButton);
        mainPanel.add(decipherByNearestFrequencyButton);

        //Finalise and display the frame
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Method to check whether the buttons used for decrypting can be pressed
    private void enableButtons()
    {
        //If both files are loaded, enable the buttons, otherwise disable both
        if (cipherLoaded == true && frequenciesLoaded == true)
        {
            decipherByRankButton.setEnabled(true);
            decipherByNearestFrequencyButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else{
            decipherByRankButton.setEnabled(false);
            decipherByNearestFrequencyButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //Method used for loading files from a file chooser
    private File loadFile()
    {
        //Get the user to choose a file
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File( System.getProperty("user.dir")));

        int fileChooserResult = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

        //If a file has been chosen, return that file. Otherwise display an error
        if (fileChooserResult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            return fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error loading file. Please try again.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            return null;
        }
    }

    //Method for loading the character frequencies file
    public File loadFrequencies()
    {
        //Load the file
        File loadedFile = loadFile();

        //If no file has been loaded, set the relevant flags to false and disable the decypting buttons
        if (loadedFile == null)
        {
            frequenciesLoaded = false;
            enableButtons();
            frequenciesFileLoadedLabel.setText("No file with character frequencies loaded");
            return loadedFile;
        }
        //If a file has been loaded, set the relevant flags to true and enable the decrypting buttons (if the other file has been loaded too)
        else
        {
            frequenciesLoaded = true;
            enableButtons();
            frequenciesFileLoadedLabel.setText("Character frequencies file loaded");
            return loadedFile;
        }
    }

    //Method for loading the ciphered file
    public File loadCiphered()
    {
        File loadedFile = loadFile();

        //If no file has been loaded, set the relevant flags to false and disable the decypting buttons
        if (loadedFile == null)
        {
            cipherLoaded = false;
            enableButtons();
            cipherFileLoadedLabel.setText("No file with text to decipher loaded");
            return loadedFile;
        }
        //If a file has been loaded, set the relevant flags to true and enable the decrypting buttons (if the other file has been loaded too)
        else
        {
            cipherLoaded = true;
            enableButtons();
            cipherFileLoadedLabel.setText("File with text to decipher loaded");
            return loadedFile;
        }
    }

    //Method used to display errors to the user
    public void displayError(String errorString)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, errorString, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    //Method that displays a message when a file has been output
    public void fileOutput()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "File deciphered and output to file \"output.txt\".");
    }

    //Add an actionlistener for every button in the program
    public void addFrequencyButtonListener(ActionListener listenForFreqButton)
    {
        frequenciesFileLoadButton.addActionListener(listenForFreqButton);
    }

    public void addCipherButtonListener(ActionListener listenForCipherButton)
    {
        cipherFileLoadButton.addActionListener(listenForCipherButton);
    }

    public void addDecipherRankButtonListener(ActionListener listenForDecipherRankButton)
    {
        decipherByRankButton.addActionListener(listenForDecipherRankButton);
    }

    public void addDecipherFrequencyButtonListener(ActionListener listenForDecipherFrequencyButton)
    {
        decipherByNearestFrequencyButton.addActionListener(listenForDecipherFrequencyButton);
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Controller
{
    //Variables that will hold the view and controller.
    private View view;
    private Model model;

    //The constructor
    public Controller(View view, Model model)
    {
        //Set the view and model
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;

        //Set an actionlistener for every button
        this.view.addCipherButtonListener(new CipherButtonListener());
        this.view.addFrequencyButtonListener(new FrequencyButtonListener());
        this.view.addDecipherRankButtonListener(new DecipherRankButtonListener());
        this.view.addDecipherFrequencyButtonListener(new DecipherFrequencyButtonListener());
    }

    //Set up a listener for every button
    class CipherButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Call the method in model to load the ciphered file when the relevant button is clicked
            model.loadCipherered(view.loadCiphered());
        }
    }

    class FrequencyButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Call  the method in the model to load the frequencies file when the relevant button is clicked
            model.loadFrequencies(view.loadFrequencies());
        }
    }

    class DecipherRankButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Decipher the file by rank and display a message
            model.decipherByRank();

            view.fileOutput();
        }
    }

    class DecipherFrequencyButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Decipher the file by frequency and display a message
            model.decipherByFrequency();

            view.fileOutput();
        }
    }

}
```

Model.java:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.*;

public class Model
{
    //Constant for the amount of letters in the alphabet
    private final int ALPHABET_LENGTH = 26;

    //HashMaps for storing the character frequencies in the frequency and cipher files
    private LinkedHashMap<Character, Float> sortedEncryptedMap;
    private LinkedHashMap<Character, Float> frequenciesMap;

    //Array holding the whole alphabet - used when loading files
    private char[] alphabet;

    //String which holds the encrypted text
    private static String encryptedFileString;

    //Enum used in the sortHashMap method to specify what hashmap to write to
    private enum ImportType {
        FREQUENCY, CIPHER
    }

    //The constructor
    public Model()
    {
        //Initialise all variables
        sortedEncryptedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

        encryptedFileString = "";

        frequenciesMap = new LinkedHashMap <>();
    }

    //Method that orders hashmaps in numerical order. ImportType necessary to check which hashmap to write to
    public void sortHashMap(HashMap<Character, Float> inputMap, ImportType importType)
    {
        //Set the keys and values to separate arraylists
        ArrayList<Character> mapKeys = new ArrayList<>(inputMap.keySet());
        ArrayList<Float> mapValues = new ArrayList<>(inputMap.values());

        //Sort the extracted keys and values
        Collections.sort(mapValues, Collections.reverseOrder());
        Collections.sort(mapKeys, Collections.reverseOrder());

        //Renitialise the hashmaps to store new data
        if (importType == ImportType.FREQUENCY)
        {
            frequenciesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        }
        else if (importType == ImportType.CIPHER)
        {
            sortedEncryptedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        }

        //Set up an iterator that will go over all the map values
        Iterator<Float> valueIterator = mapValues.iterator();

        //Double while loop that will terminate after the last value is reached
        while (valueIterator.hasNext()) {
            Float currentValue = valueIterator.next();
            Iterator<Character> keyIterator = mapKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                Character currentKey = keyIterator.next();
                //Check if key and value match
                Float comp1 = inputMap.get(currentKey);
                Float comp2 = currentValue;

                if (comp1 == comp2) {
                    keyIterator.remove();

                    //Put new found value into the right place according to the sorted arraylists
                    if (importType == ImportType.FREQUENCY)
                    {
                        frequenciesMap.put(currentKey, currentValue);
                    }
                    else if (importType == ImportType.CIPHER)
                    {
                        sortedEncryptedMap.put(currentKey, currentValue);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Method for loading the frequencies file
    public void loadFrequencies(File inputFile)
    {
        try 
        {
            //Set up a scanner and input the loaded file into it
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (inputFile);

            //Clear the hashmap for storing new frequencies
            frequenciesMap = new LinkedHashMap <Character, Float>();

            //Temporary hashmap for unsorted input
            LinkedHashMap<Character, Float> tempMap = new LinkedHashMap <Character, Float>();

            //Keep reading the file until th end
            while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                //Store the line currently being checked
                String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();

                //Separate the letter in the string
                Character currentLetter = nextLine.charAt(0);

                //Separate the frequency from the string
                float currentValue = Float.parseFloat(nextLine.substring(1, nextLine.length()));

                //Store the frequency and letter in the temporary hashmap
                tempMap.put(currentLetter, currentValue);
            }

            //Sort the hashmap and store it in a variable outside of this method
            sortHashMap(tempMap, ImportType.FREQUENCY);
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Print stack trace if there's an error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Method for loading the ciphered text file
    public void loadCipherered(File inputFile)
    {
        try {
            //Input the text from the ciphered file into a string
            if (inputFile == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Set up a scanner and input the loaded file into it
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (inputFile);

            //Clear the string which holds the input file and the hashmap that will hold the letter frequencies
            sortedEncryptedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
            encryptedFileString = "";

            //Flag to check whether it's the first line of the file that's being checked.
            boolean firstLine = true;

            while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                //If it's not the first line add a newline character (due to the nature of scanner.nextLine, this is necessary to preserve new line)
                if (firstLine == false)
                {
                    encryptedFileString += "\n";
                }

                //Add text from the file to the stirng
                encryptedFileString += scanner.nextLine();

                firstLine = false;
            }

            //Ignore cases
            encryptedFileString = encryptedFileString.toLowerCase();

            //When the file has been loaded, count the occurances of each character and assign them to a HashMap
            Map<Character, Integer> occuranceMap = new HashMap <Character, Integer>();

            //Populate the hashmap with the alphabet and initially, set each count to 0
            for(int i = 0; i< ALPHABET_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                occuranceMap.put(alphabet[i], 0);
            }

            //Iterate through the encrypted file string and count the amount of times each letter occurs
            for  (int i = 0; i < encryptedFileString.length(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_LENGTH; j++)
                {
                    if (alphabet[j] == encryptedFileString.charAt(i) )
                    {
                        occuranceMap.put(alphabet[j], occuranceMap.get(alphabet[j]) + 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Caclulate the total number of letters (excluding other characters) in the encrypted file
            int totalLetters = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                totalLetters += occuranceMap.get(alphabet[i]);
            }

            //Make a hashmap that contains the percentages of each letter
            LinkedHashMap<Character, Float> percentageMap = new LinkedHashMap <Character, Float>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                percentageMap.put(alphabet[i], ((float)occuranceMap.get(alphabet[i]) / (float)totalLetters) * 100 );
            }

            //Sort the hashmap with percentages as values in order of highest percentage occurance
            sortHashMap(percentageMap, ImportType.CIPHER);
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Print stack trace if there's an error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Method for deciphering the text purely by the rank of each character
    public void decipherByRank()
    {
        try
        {
            //Set up a filewriter to write to a file
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("output.txt");

            //Split up the keys from each of the character frequencies hashmaps.
            ArrayList<Character> orderedCharacterFrequencies = new ArrayList<Character>(frequenciesMap.keySet());
            ArrayList<Character> orderedEncryptedFrequencies = new ArrayList<Character>(sortedEncryptedMap.keySet());

            //Declare a stringwriter to write the output string as it's much faster than writing to a string
            StringWriter outputWriter = new StringWriter();

            //Iterate through the encrypted string, checking every character
            for (int i = 0; i < encryptedFileString.length(); i++)
            {
                //Flag for checking whether the letter has been replaced or not - whether it's a letter or another character
                boolean replaced = false;

                //If the character being checked is a letter, replace it with a letter from the frequencies hashmap at the same rank
                for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_LENGTH; j++)
                {
                    if (encryptedFileString.charAt(i) == orderedEncryptedFrequencies.get(j))
                    {
                        outputWriter.write(orderedCharacterFrequencies.get(j));
                        replaced = true;
                    }
                }

                //If the character hasnt been found in the arraylists, is not a letter and therefore should be kept the same
                if (replaced == false)
                {
                    outputWriter.write(encryptedFileString.charAt(i));
                }
            }

            //Write the string to a file
            fileWriter.write(outputWriter.toString());

            //Close the filewriter
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Print stack trace if there's an error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Method for deciphering the encyrpted text by the nearest frequency
    public void decipherByFrequency()
    {
        try
        {
            //Set up a filewriter to write to a file
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("output.txt");

            //Split up the keys from each of the character frequencies hashmaps
            ArrayList<Character> orderedCharacterFrequencyKeys = new ArrayList<Character>(frequenciesMap.keySet());
            ArrayList<Character> orderedEncryptedFrequencyKeys = new ArrayList<Character>(sortedEncryptedMap.keySet());

            //Split up the values from each of the character frequency hashmaps
            ArrayList<Float> orderedCharacterFrequencyValues = new ArrayList<Float>(frequenciesMap.values());
            ArrayList<Float> orderedEncryptedFrequencyValues = new ArrayList<Float>(sortedEncryptedMap.values());

            //Declare a stringwriter to write the output string as it's much faster than writing to a string
            StringWriter outputWriter = new StringWriter();

            //Iterate through the encrypted string, checking every character
            for (int i = 0; i < encryptedFileString.length(); i++)
            {
                //Flag for checking whether the letter has been replaced or not - whether it's a letter or another character
                boolean replaced = false;

                //Check if the character is a letter
                for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_LENGTH; j++)
                {
                    if (encryptedFileString.charAt(i) == orderedEncryptedFrequencyKeys.get(j))
                    {
                        //Variable for storing the difference in percentages of any characters
                        float difference = 150.0f;

                        float currentCharacterPercentage = orderedEncryptedFrequencyValues.get(j);

                        //Index of currently the closest percentage
                        int closestCharacterIndex = 0;

                        //terate through other letters, checking which will give the lowest difference
                        for (int k = 0; k < ALPHABET_LENGTH; k++)
                        {
                            if ( Math.abs(currentCharacterPercentage - orderedCharacterFrequencyValues.get(k) ) < difference )
                            {
                                closestCharacterIndex = k;
                                difference = Math.abs(currentCharacterPercentage - orderedCharacterFrequencyValues.get(k));
                            }
                        }

                        //Replace the file of the lowest difference and write it to the stringwriter
                        outputWriter.write(orderedCharacterFrequencyKeys.get(closestCharacterIndex));
                        replaced = true;
                    }
                }

                //If the character hasnt been found in the arraylists, is not a letter and therefore should be kept the same
                if (replaced == false)
                {
                    outputWriter.write(encryptedFileString.charAt(i));
                }
            }

            //Write the string to a file
            fileWriter.write(outputWriter.toString());

            //Close the filewriter
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Print stack trace if there's an error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declare an instance of view and model and pass those to the controller
        View mainView = new View();

        Model mainModel = new Model();

        Controller mainController = new Controller(mainView, mainModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly, this is not far off been about right for a MVC (based on my understand of the intention). Personally, I would have a `ViewListener` instead of allowing the controller to register against the buttons directly (as it exposes details about the implementation that neither the controller or model care about), but otherwise is almost the way I'd expect to see the interaction.  Remember though, Swing is already a MVC, so you're wrapping another MVC on top of it

Comment: One thing I might suggest is starting with interfaces, these should describe the responsibilities of each layer, model, view, controller and define the ways in which these can interact with each other (like listeners/events each layer produce, etc)